# python making a button that does print preview without closing the previous window and yetgoing to the next .py

Tags: python, subprocess, pyinstaller, exe

Currently making a program with 2 .py files, I want to set up a button that takes a value in an array in the first.py file and moves it along to second.py file using the subprocess option to make an exe file

button():
subprocess.Popen("second.exe")

is there any way of making the subprocess carry a value along with it to the next file which will be an exe without using the import functions because it tends to break my program if I use any of the normal imports.

this is really important because i am trying to avoid putting these two .py files in a single file because it is extremely big

Comment: _it tends to break my program if I use any of the normal imports_ -- that's not really a good reason.  If your program is written correctly, `import` won't break it.  You can certainly pass command-line arguments to your second app, if that's all it takes.  The `subprocess.Popen` call does not "make an exe file", as you said.  If you have built an exe from your script that's fine, but otherwise you'd just call `["python","second.py","parameter"]`.

Comment: is there a way to pass an array instead of just a parameter? and yeah i have had to convert to exe because of pyinstaller

Comment: You have the `stdin` handle for the process, so you can convert your array to text and stream it into the app, just like a Unix pipeline.